# AIX 6.1 versus AIX 7.1 strange behaviour

Tags: ksh, aix, arithmetic

I have this logic in a ksh script on AIX 6.1 and it works fine.

```
integer loop_count=0
integer sleep_interval=5
integer alarm_interval=60
if (( $loop_count*$sleep_interval%$alarm_interval -eq 0 ))
then 
   echo "hello"
else
    echo "bye"
fi
```

On AIX 7.1 is gives me this error.

> line 4:  *5%60 -eq 0 : arithmetic syntax error

If I change it to

```
if (( $sleep_interval*$loop_count%$alarm_interval -eq 0 ))
```

so the variable that could be zero is not first, it works fine.  Many other ways to fix it as well, but it's curious to me that the logic that was valid in 6.1 fails in 7.1.

Comment: What is the sh-bang (first) line of the script?

Comment: Check the versions of `ksh` on 6.1 and 7.1. And better contact IBM support, seems like feature (or bug)